# How can I add setInterval() in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

I am receiving a image from server through *Action Script*.  I want to  receive the image in a continuous manner.

I am new to this Action Script and write the following code
I am writing in Flash how can I add `setInterval() to it.

```
var my_pb:mx.controls.ProgressBar;                        
my_pb.mode = "manual";                       
this.createEmptyMovieClip("img_mc", 999);                  
var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();            
var mclListenerbject = new Object();                   
mclListener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip)  {          
    my_pb.label = "loading: "+target_mc._name;              
};                    
mclListener.onLoadProgress =function(target_mc:MovieClip,            
                     numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) {              
    var pctLoaded:Number = Math.ceil(100*(numBytesLoaded/numBytesTotal));                            
    my_pb.setProgress(numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal);              
};              
my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);                    
my_mcl.loadClip("123.php?device=9113......", img_mc);
```

thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example about how to use setInterval in ActionScript 3

```
var myInterval:uint = setInterval (testInterval, 1000);

function testInterval():void
{
      trace('test interval');

      // to stop the interval
      clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

Concerning ActionScript 2, I believe the following code will work fine as well, but you can also read more about in the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000600.html).

```
 var myInterval = setInterval(testInterval, 1000); 

 function testInterval()
 {
      // include your logic scope here

      // to clear the interval
      clearInterval(myInterval);
 }
```

Comment: I want to Know In Actionscript 2.0

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer with a version in AS2, also link to the official documentation. The tag of your question is concerning AS3, that's why.

Comment: Yes, I noticed after a double check! :)

Comment: I have already that documentation...But Can not find any solution..  I have tried this but No  Image is recieving

Comment: I believe the blinking you will need to investigate a bit more. Glad to know that is working, so we can close this question! :)

Comment: its great... but  i want to run continouesly..without blinking

Comment: Try to reduce the delay of the interval

Comment: is there any other method to run without blink .. or by adding some timer to it

Comment: You can try a loop to load all images, or create a timer, also have some kind of transition (fade in/out)

Comment: Is there any method for for increase or decrease   speed of  timer by button

Comment: You can use the getter/setter delay to increase or decrease a timer instance delay.

Comment: i have to use Button  One for increase .. one for decrease